# EFI partition not found installing in Legacy mode, UEFI error installing in UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 and I installed Ubuntu in `/dev/sda`. Sadly once the operation is completed if I try to use boot-repair it says EFI partition is not found.

I'm pretty sure I have to install as I did, in legacy..because I own a UEFI system but apparently a legacy Windows 10.
Still in my BIOS I can't retrace Windows boot manager, I tried with `bootmngr.efi` but to the system it looks like there is no boot device avilable. By now it boots as partition 1. Disk 1 is where Windows OS is installed, I instead installed Ubuntu on disk 0. Can someone tell me if this is the actual problem? I decided to install on disk 0 because there's much more space in there. 
If i type sudo parted -l the result is

> Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
>   Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
>   Partition Table: gpt
>   Disk Flags:
>
> Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                           Flags
>    1      1049kB  135MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
>    2      135MB   1000GB  1000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
>
> Model: SCSI DISK (scsi)
>   Disk /dev/sdb: 16.0GB
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
>   Partition Table: msdos
>   Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  16.0GB  16.0GB  primary  fat32        boot, lba

But if i try to install ubuntu in uefi mode  a windows pops up stating **This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be existing operating systems already installed using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.**
This is weird considering that according to the system settings the bios is UEFI.

Comment: If you system was purchased from Dell with Windows 10 (or 8) then it has to be UEFI. post this in your question above: `sudo parted -l`

Comment: should i select a gpt partition for uefi computer?

Comment: You have gpt on sda & MBR(msdos) on sdb. Better if all drives are gpt if you want UEFI. But sda only has the required Windows msftres/Microsoft reserved partition. Did you erase Windows?  If also re-installing Windows do that first as it wants several partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: well..no i'm using Windows right now!! I know perfectly how the partition works..but i don't get why i get errors installing uefi, and installing Legacy i couldn't access ubuntu.

Comment: The reason why you see just a partition i think/hope is due just to the fact that i shrinked that volume. I tried to use Rufus to have gpt in dev/sdb but keep getting the same error

Comment: Lets see all the details: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26380372/    this is what I get after installing linux as legacy. Sadly i think i have windows in UEFI but if I try installing in UEFI it tells me I am forcing the installation as reported in the originary question

Comment: You are not showing Windows? Nor an ESP - efi system partition. And Ubuntu is in BIOS boot mode on gpt drive.Do you have another drive with Windows that is not plugged in? If so, plug it in & rerun report. If not, is Windows still boot? You also have many, many UEFI entries, and they look like duplicates. There used to be issues with too many entries. See efibootmgr -b examples in `man efibootmgr` & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289179&p=13331743#post13331743

Comment: Yes I installed Ubuntu in bios mode because otherwise he gave me the error. I didn't unplug anything. All I know is that i have installed ubuntu in disk0..where i had enough space, and windows is installed in disk 1

Comment: i just used efibootmgr to delete duplicates, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is Windows drive plugged in? Report only showed one drive. And drive order is an issue as grub only installs to ESP - efi system partition on drive seen as sda. Installer may not be complaining, since you have BIOS boot grub installed. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to convert current install to UEFI by uninstalling grub-pc and installing grub-efi-amd64. You must boot live installer in UEFI mode & then add Boot-Repair, so in UEFI mode.

Comment: I'm using Windows to answer, so yes it is plugged in. I don't know why it doesn't show up!! I just uninstalled ubuntu..you think i should install it in legacy mode and than try to convert?